# Xamarin WebView iOS detect Scrolling event

Tags: ios, xamarin, webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Setup: I'm using Xamarin (and Xamarin.Forms) developing an app with an embedded browser.

My issue:
I have a WebView and I'm trying to detect when a user is scrolling, and whether it is Up or Down.

So far, I have created a Custom WebViewRenderer for the iOS-project. But how does one subscribe to scrolling events?
Googling makes me believe that overriding the WebViewRenderer's

```
OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
```

should be the right way, but I can't seem to find any documentation/leads on how to go further. 
Does anyone know, or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: check this webviewrendenrer. 

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/WebViewRenderer.cs

and this example in android always the android code is very similar of iOS you can replicate the same code.

 https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54365/android-enabling-scrolling-for-a-webview-inside-a-scrollview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `MKWebView` and `UIWebView` contain a `UIScrollView` that you can assign a `UIScrollViewDelegate` to its `ScrollView.Delegate` property and track `scrollViewDidScroll` to determine the panning direction:

```
public class UIScrollViewDelegate : NSObject, IUIScrollViewDelegate
{
    [Export("scrollViewDidScroll:")]
    public void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        var translation = scrollView.PanGestureRecognizer.TranslationInView(scrollView.Superview);
        Console.WriteLine($"Scrolling {(translation.Y > 0 ? "Down" : "Up")}");
    }
}
```